# How to emulate usb-mtp device with virt-manager?

Tags: configuration, qemu, libvirt, virt-manager, mtp

I am trying to emulate an mtp device with virt-manager. I see at https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/system/devices/usb.html that usb-mtp,rootdir=dir as in -device usb-mtp,rootdir=dir could be used to do this with qemu. How can I configure virt-manager to do this (custom xml welcome)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find an xml equivalent of the command, but I was able to change the xml to run the command directly. I needed to insert `xmlns:qemu="http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0"` in the beginning `<domain>` element and kept the existing `type="kvm"` and put

```
<qemu:commandline>  
    <qemu:arg value="-device"/>
    <qemu:arg value="usb-mtp,rootdir=dir"/>
</qemu:commandline>
```

as the last element before the closing `</domain>`. https://blog.vmsplice.net/2011/04/how-to-pass-qemu-command-line-options.html and #virt irc on OFTC was helpful with this. **Warning**: if a change doesn't parse correctly when saving via the virt-manager xml editing pane then it may be removed so take necessary precautions before saving and to check after.